# brew --head update behaviour

Tags: homebrew

[I understand what passing the `--head` option during install does,](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/78984/what-does-brew-head-mean?rq=1) but, I'm not sure how it effect future behaviour. That is, if I pass `--head` explicitly when installing a package, will subsequent updates

- Aways grab from the HEAD commit from SVM?
- Only update if the latest release > than the HEAD at the time I explicitly provided the `--head` option during

Additionally, if its the former, how would I then get back into following the "normal" releases?